# Is there a command line tool that allows online search for linux commands?

Tags: command-line

I know I can do `man commandname` to find the docs for a specific command, but many times I simply Google "how to list all installed packages sorted by size" or "how to find file by content in a folder recursively", then usually I get to ask ubuntu / superuser / stackoverflow and 99/100 the accepted / highest voted answer contains the desired command, I copy, paste, and profit.

My question is this, is there any command line utility, that does something like this:

```
$ howto "get available disk space"
```

and returns

```
$ according to Stackoverflow, the command is "df -h" with 90% accuracy 
$ 1) [run]
$ 2) run as sudo
$ 3) give next suggestion 
$ 4) this is not right! (you'll be able to provide your suggestion next)
$ 5) exit
```

It's a bit like http://gkoberger.github.io/stacksort/ based on the alt text of this XKCD: http://xkcd.com/1185/

Couldn't find anything like it, does it exist?

Answer (score 2):

While it is not as full-featured as google, you can find local commands with `apropos`.  For example:

```
$ apropos "disk space"
df (1)               - report file system disk space usage
```

`apropos` searches through man pages.  Its argument can contain wildcards (`apropos -w`) or a regex (`apropos -r`).

`man apropos` explains:

> ```
>    Each manual page has a short description available within
>    it.   apropos  searches the descriptions for instances of
>    keyword.
>
>    keyword is usually a regular expression, as if  (-r)  was
>    used,  or  may contain wildcards (-w), or match the exact
>    keyword (-e).  Using these options, it may  be  necessary
>    to quote the keyword or escape (\) the special characters
>    to stop the shell from interpreting them.
>
>    The standard matching rules  allow  matches  to  be  made
>    against the page name and word boundaries in the descrip‐
>    tion.
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there is! it's a Siri for command line: https://github.com/pickhardt/betty